# Hibernate / JPA; Can I have an indexed List as a first class entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Let's say I have a `Foos' table:

```
create table Foos (
  id number not null,
  index number not null,
  label varchar2(256)
);
```

and class:

```
// Sans JPA cause I'm lazy
public class Foo {
  private int id;
  private int index;
  private String label;
}
```

*If* I had a super class and the appropriate table / foreign key I could do something like this:

```
@Entity
public class SuperFoo {
  private int id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="superFoo")
  @OrderColumn(name"index")
  private List<Foo> foos;
  // snip
}
```

And that would work great. I could add, remove and reorder items in that list and Hibernate would sort out the index column for me whenever I persisted `SuperFoo`.

However, in my case **I don't have a super class**. All I have is my `Foos` table, that represents a list of values that can be arbitrarily ordered.

While it's entirely possible to manage this myself (i.e. populate index myself when saving, order by index when loading) I'm wondering: **is there a way to get hibernate / JPA to manage this for me?**

**Does Hibernate / JPA support indexed Lists as first class Entities?**

Comment: So I've solved this in my situation by rejigging my data structures a bit in a way that works specifically for my situation, however the general question (can indexed lists be first class Entities) is still valid.

Comment: I would like to know that, too.